# Solving integral using Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I am trying to solve given integral:
$$
\oint_{|z+i| = 1} \frac{z}{(z-1)(z^2+2)}\;\; dz
$$
Rewriting it I get this:
$$
\oint_{|z+i| = 1} \frac{z}{(z-1)(z-i\sqrt{2})(z+i\sqrt{2})}\;\; dz
$$
Area $|z+i|=1$ is circle with radius $1$ and center at $-i$ right?

So only point in area is $z=-i\sqrt{2}$?

Then implementing Cauchy's integral formula:
$$
2\pi i \; f(-i\sqrt{2}) = \oint_{|z+i| = 1} \frac{\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-i\sqrt{2})}}{(z+i\sqrt{2})}\;\; dz
$$
Where $f$ is:
$$
f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z-i\sqrt{2})}
$$

I get that result of starting integral is
$$
-\frac{\pi}{3}(\sqrt{2} + i)
$$

But my textbook is saying that result is 
$$
-\frac{\pi}{2}(1 + i)
$$

Can you point me out if I am missing something? Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: The center of the circle is $-i$, not $(0,-i)$.

Comment: Your work looks right to me

Comment: Try double-check your problem if you wrote it correctly maybe? I reached the same result as yours.

Answer (score 1):

I get $2\pi i f(-i\sqrt 2)=2\pi i\dfrac {-i\sqrt 2}{(-i\sqrt 2-1)(-2i\sqrt 2)}=\pi i\dfrac 1{(-i\sqrt 2-1)}=-\pi i\dfrac {(1-\sqrt 2 i)}3=-\dfrac \pi 3(i+\sqrt 2)$.